# Resco controls demo - is this meant to work with VS2008? AAARRRGGGHHH!

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I've downloaded the Resco controls demo "MobileFormsToolkitEvaluation.2010.msi". Surely this works with VS2008? I've tried everything I can think of to add the controls to the toolbox but they appear greyed out. It all seems good in VS2003 but I can't get them working in VS2008. I've emailed Resco but they won't answer until tomorrow (if at all). Help :(

Cheers
Mark

Comment: If I open a desktop winform project in VS2008 then all the Resco controls are available but not with a mobile project.

Comment: In VS2008 I've run "Reset Toolbox" and now I have the tabs "Resco Desktop Controls" and "Resco Device Controls". If I open a mobile winform then they are all greyed out. If I open a desktop winform then they are ALL enabled including the mobile device controls. WTF is going on here??

Answer (score 0):

What version of the CF are you targeting?  It actually makes a difference, and getting device controls to work for CF 3.5 [can be, in some cases, impossible](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/11/26/Studio08sToolboxAndCompactFrameworkAssemblies.aspx).

Comment: CTacke to the rescue! How are you? I've just got it working now. I think that the control install files that came with thier MobileApp demo install was an old version. I've downloaded another one and reinstalled and now the controls are appearing in the toolbox. So much wasted time :(

Comment: Just a final comment. I've been playing with the Resco list control for the last day and it's very nice! They were also quite responsive with email support.